# Can I set the password of a JDBC connection from the Connection Pool? (Tomcat 5.5.17)

Tags: java, tomcat, connection-pooling

I have a connection pool set in the tomcat server context.xml (connection used by several webapps so seems the best place for it).

However, I don't like having passwords hard-coded in the file. Is there any way for me to retrieve the password from elsewhere (secure password store) and set it pragmatically at the time the pooled connections are established?

Thank you

Ryan

Comment: Take a look at the final section of http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Securing_tomcat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [Custom Resource Factory](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#Adding%20Custom%20Resource%20Factories), you can code your factory to create javax.sql.DataSource object or a DBCP (or such) based connection pooling facade object, and have your custom code for getting and setting the username/password for the connection.

Do note that if you're looking for extra security -- the pragmatic way would be to use filesystem security for securing your context.xml file, as adding extra layers (such as your custom implementation for the resource factory), won't make the system more secure, as you still need the password for the secure password store configured somewhere -- you'll end up getting the chicken or the egg problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to implement a single sign-on for your web application (e.g. using [JOSSO](http://www.josso.org/confluence/display/JOSSO1/JOSSO+-+Java+Open+Single+Sign-On+Project+Home)). Note that it might be a significant overhead for a small project, but this should solve your problem. Apart from this solution, there are vendor specific applications like Secure External Password Store from Oracle. Another platform dependent example: you can configure PostgreSQL pg_hba.conf. Try the following authentication options:

- Authenticate using SSL client
  certificates.
- Authenticate using the    Pluggable 
  Authentication Modules    (PAM)
  service provided by the    operating
  system.
- Authenticate using    an    LDAP
  server.
- ... and many others

Edit: In one of the projects we used 3DES to encrypt the password. And yes, the key was hardcoded in application :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, I appreciate the time you took to answer. However, I am trying to stick to the standard tomcat DBCP and simply 'bolting on' my password retrieval, so I marked the answer below as the acepted solution. Thank you. Ryan